# This highly rated question from 2009 put on hold today. What is the purpose of that?

Tags: discussion, flags

[Near-Duplicate Image Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034900/near-duplicate-image-detection)

It has been voted up 84 times, has an accepted answer with 59 votes and a +50 rep, and a handful of other useful answers.

What is the purpose of putting it on hold? 5 people flagged it as "too broad".

Should old questions like these be flaggable?

---

**Edit**

I guess I didn't express my question clearly enough:

This one is obviously a useful question, with lots of useful answers. This is probably one of those questions that comes on top when you google for "how do I compare images" or something like that. Why delete such a question? We'll just get lots of similar questions posted.

Comment: Without getting into that specific example, yes we should be able to clean up and maintain old content just as much as new. Why not?

Comment: If it is in fact too broad, absolutely. Why not.

Comment: "Y R U CLOSIN MY QS? LOOK AT THIS Q ITS JUST LIKE MINE AND ITS GOT A BAZILLION UPVOTES!!!!11" <-- fifteen million people like this are why.

Comment: closing isn't deleting.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I did not realize that. In that case I don't care. Thanks!

Comment: note that closing can _lead_ to deletion. For instance, get -3 score + close, then 3 people vote to delete, and question is gone.

Comment: "This is probably one of those questions that comes on top when you google for "how do I compare images" or something like that. Why delete such a question?" The answer just links to other sources that tell you where the answer is.  It would be *far* better if *those* sources were the first thing that came up when you searched for this, not a question that links you to them without providing any other useful information.

Comment: @Jean-François just to note: 3 delete votes on a Q is the minimum required - it can be up to 10 based on the scores of the question and its answers...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is the purpose of putting it on hold?

The purpose is the same as why any other question is put on hold.  We don't want people posting answers to these questions, and we want people reading these questions (as well as automated tools of the site) to know that they're not acceptable questions by the site's standards.

> It has been voted up 84 times, has an accepted answer with 59 votes and a +50 rep, and a handful of other useful ansers.

None of which affect whether or not the question is Too Broad (or meriting closure for any other reason).

> 5 people flagged it as "too broad".

Because it's Too Broad.

> Should old questions like these be flaggable?

Yes.  Since old questions aren't all on topic, clear, specific, objective, etc., it's important that they be able to be closed.

Comment: I was wondering why we don't see the "delete" button. Because it has so many votes? Maybe closing isn't enough, this should be locked or deleted. locked is good, so noone can decide to reopen (and it allows the question to remain as an "historical" question)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A question need to have a score of -3, or have been closed for 3? (or is it 2?) days before (non-moderator) delete votes can be cast on it.  This is to give the OP (or other people) time to fix it before it's deleted.  The only reason to lock it would be to prevent people from reopening it, which is something I wouldn't worry about until it actually happens.  I also don't see the question as being so useful that it would merit a historical lock.  The bar is *really* high there.

Comment: ah ok, I just saw the "10 hours ago". Makes sense. Maybe I wouldn't delete it, but locking it would be a good idea to avoid more voting & possible reopening.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No.  For one, you don't use a historical lock preemptively.  If people are constantly reopening it (or deleting it if it's of such enormous value that deleting it is entirely unacceptable) then a lock can be put on to stop it, but it's best avoided if it's not necessary.  Next, the question isn't "so enormously useful" that it merits a historical lock.  As mentioned in another comment, the top answer is just linking to other questions/sources, which still exist; that post isn't particularly valuable, certainly not enough for a historical lock at any rate.

Comment: "I also don't see the question as being so useful that it would merit a historical lock": you mean [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In my opinion a large portion of historically locked posts don't merit a historical lock.  That one included.  That some have it when they shouldn't isn't a reason to use it more, it's a reason to unlock those.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's not like the page is full of original cartoons that don't exist anywhere else.  They're widely shared cartoons.  It's not like it's hard to find programmer cartoons if you're just looking to have some fun, *so many* websites cater to it that it's not a service that dies if that question goes away.  Honestly, the question is also at a pretty high risk of being removed via DMCA, as it's just one giant walking copyright violation. If SO moved it to a blog they'd be opening themselves up to lawsuits, because you know that the people posting those comics aren't the authors.

Comment: good point. In that case, why not flagging it for deletion as "plagiarism" ? that makes sense. Crap: we cannot flag a locked post...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You can't flag historically locked posts.